# delete large list in SharePoint2010

Tags: list, list-view-threshold

I have a List in sharePoint with 64095 items , I want to delete list completely , but I can't delete list beacuse of number of items. The error message is similar to:

```
The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold
```

what should I do?

Comment: I could delete my list according to this link , it was useful for me:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=261&Web=48e6fdd1-17db-4543-b2f9-6fc7185484fc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could delete my list according to this link , it was useful for me:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=261&Web=48e6fdd1-17db-4543-b2f9-6fc7185484fc